# random variables function

Tags: random-variables

consider flipping two fair coins. Let $X=1$ if the first coin is heads, and $X=0$ if the first coin is tails. Let $Y=1$ if the second coin is heads, and $Y=5$ if the second coin is tails. Let $Z=XY$. What is the probability function of $Z$?

can someone please explain what does $Z=XY$ means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Z = XY$ literally means to take the outcome you observe for $X$ and the outcome you observe for $Y$, and multiply them to obtain your observation for $Z$.  For example, if you observe the first coin is heads and the second coin is tails, then $$Z = XY = 1 \times 5 = 5.$$

Comment: How do I find the probability function of Z in this case?

Comment: never mind, got it, thanks.